# C++: A misguided case of function overloading

Tags: c++, function, overloading

I wrote and  executed the following code in c++:

```
    int calc(int x=10,int y=100);int a,b,s,p,m;void main()
{clrscr();cout<<"enter the two numbers:";cin>>a>>b;s=calc(a,b);p=calc(a);`m=calc();cout<<"\n sum:"<<s;cout<<"\n product:"<<p;cout<<"\n subtraction:"<<m;getch();}
int calc(int a)
{int t;b=100;t=a*b;return t;}
int calc(int a,int b)
{int t;t=a+b;return t;}
int calc()
{int t;t=b-a;return t;}
```

I See that only one function is being called and is giving the correct output. For example: 3 and 4 will give 7, but from multiply it will be 101. I am  not very good with c++ concepts. An explanation would be useful.
Regards.

Comment: Essentially, it's because of your formatting.

Comment: Can you please be specific? Thank you..

Comment: If `main` would also see declaration of `calc(int)` and `calc()`, you would have ambiguous call with `calc(int = 10, ,int = 100)`

Comment: Thaks a lot! That was really helpful

Comment: If it's "unexplainable", what are you asking for?

Comment: From the way your question is worded now, it is completely unclear what your problem is (and why formatting should have anything to do with it).

Comment: You provided default values. So, if you just pass one value how does it know to use the single param version or the two param version with the second defaulted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point is

`s=calc(a,b);
p=calc(a);
m=calc();`

All match function

```
int calc(int a, int b)
  {
  int t;
  t=a+b;
 return t;
  }
```

Because it has defined default values, in case you don's specify input:

```
int calc(int x=10, int y=100);
```

It means that if you use

```
calc(1);
```

It will use

```
calc(1, 100);
```

BTW, this does not even compile on VisualStudio 2015, because with error:

error C2668: 'calc': ambiguous call to overloaded function

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually this was asked by one of my students. Thank you for clearing the concept

Comment: But from MSDN : _If two candidates are judged to be equally good, preference goes to a candidate that does not have optional parameters for which arguments were omitted in the call. This is a consequence of a general preference in overload resolution for candidates that have fewer parameters_ Which is different than the behaviour described in the question. Do you have any idea why? REference [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674417/conflicting-overloaded-methods-with-optional-parameters]

Comment: This was not compiled with VS so VS features don't matter

Comment: @Benoit - it was example Edit. I'm not smarter than people designing VS and it's compiler, so If they say it's wrong it's most likely wrong. And they give explanation.

Comment: @AvantikaSaini Link you provided is for C#. C++ has different rules http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943596/function-overloading-two-functions-only-differ-by-a-default-parameter

Comment: @MaciekGrynda oops! sorry my bad

Comment: @MaciekGrynda : my comment was adressed to AvantikaSaini because his link came from msdn. I didn't mean to be agressive. An didnt notice your last remark, neither the fact the link was about c#. My bad.

Comment: I dont see why people have downvoted my question.. :( .. I see so many good answers and explainations..

Comment: I don't know but you should generally at least indent properly your code, and leave one blanck line bewteen your different function/classes if there are some.

Answer (score 0):

because you gave default values. When you call `calc(a)` with `a=3`, your prgramm actually runs `calc(3,100)`

Answer (score 0):

Code is so strange at my first sight.

First of all, you should know global a = 3, b = 4 all the time.
both parameters are provided the first time call calc so the result is 7.
the second time, only one paramter provided, so a = 3, b = 100
and the last time no paramater, a = 10, b = 100.

```
int calc(int x = 10, int y = 100)
{
    int t;
    t = x + y;
    return t;
}
```

this may be easier to understand?

Comment: Thanks. It was actually written by a guy who actually thought he was quite expert at messing with logic. Before giving any answers to him I just wanted to be sure of the answer myself . That's why i put the question on my behalf and not his.The end result turned out to be pretty good!